# Pass url after trailing slash to proxy_pass

Tags: nginx

How do you redirect everything after* the trailing slash to an internal server? I hope that made sense. Example: `www.foo.com/v2/api` should go to `localhost:3000/api` or `www.foo.com/v2/something` goes to `localhost:3000/something`. I have this:

```sh
location ~ ^/v2/(.*) {
   #rewrite ^/(.*)$ $1 break;
   proxy_pass http://localhost:3000/$1;
}
```

```
foo.com/v2/<ANYTHING-HERE-SHOULD-MOVE-BEHIND-PORT-3000>
```

*see above

Based on the web, this should work, right? But it's not. An nginx task was thrown at me without notice but by looking at that, should it have worked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to define a [`resolver`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#resolver) as you are using [`proxy_pass`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass) with variables.

However, the functionality you are looking for can be achieved more simply using a prefix location rather than a regular expression:

```
location /v2/ {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3000/;
}
```